# Powershell Web Access leads to 404

Tags: powershell, iis, ssl, server, certificate

I have installed POWA on 2012 R2 trough powershell.

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name WindowsPowerShellWebAccess -IncludeManagementTools

Install-PswaWebApplication

Add-PswaAothorizationRule * * *
```

Navigating to https://server/powa or https://server.fqdn/powa leads to a 404 "File or directory not found". I've checked the IIS and forlder structure and everything is there. I've tried IE and chrome but both returning this error.

- SSL is activated on the powa application
- Pool is running with elevated user and correct right allocation
- I am using a domain certificate for SSL

What am i missing here?

Thanks a lot and Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificate was not valid for this procedure, used another domain certificate that met the FQDM requirements.